# Cannot use "page" and "post" layouts of Jekyll theme in GitHub pages?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I started experimenting with GitHub pages and Jekyll.

You can find my repository here:

https://github.com/braek/braek.github.io

And the website you can find here:

http://www.braek.be

I created a post and configured "page" as layout, but the page is not rendered in the Cayman theme that I selected in the GitHub pages settings.

The same goes for a post with layout set to "post".

Is this normal? Do I need to add these templates myself in the _layouts directory?

Kind regards,
B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Cayman theme](https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman) does not have a `page` layout. It only has a `default` layout.

**You have to build the `page` layout yourself**.

The [instructions on how to create new layouts & modify the default one](https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman#layouts) are in the repository of the Cayman theme, copied below for simplicity:

> #### Layouts
>
> If you'd like to change the theme's HTML layout:
>
> 1. [Copy the original template](https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman/blob/master/_layouts/default.html) from the theme's repository
>    (*Pro-tip: click "raw" to make copying easier*)
> 2. Create a file called `/_layouts/default.html` in your site
> 3. Paste the default layout content copied in the first step
> 4. Customize the layout as you'd like

Comment: OK! I was starting to suspect that the layouts were just missing, but needed some confirmation on that. :-)